# Reading related data is throwing a LINQ error in my application

Tags: c#, linq

I'm looking for some help with my MVC5 application (using Entity Framework) when selecting related data, I thought I had this working correctly but now I'm not so sure as I am getting an error when I try to select my data in a specific way.

I have 4 tables that store related data.  These are:

```
Hive1
- ID (int, PK)
- Name (varchar)

Hive2
- ID (int, PK)
- Location (varchar)
- Hive_ID (int) (relationship to ID of Hive 1)

Hive3
- ID (int, pk)
- Propulsion (carchar)
- Hive_ID (int) (relationship to ID of Hive 1)

Hive4
- ID (int, pk)
- BHP (varchar)
- Hive_ID (int) (relationship to ID of Hive 1)
```

So Hive2, Hive3, Hive4 all have a relationship from Hive_ID to the ID of Hive1.  Since I am showing related data I created a view model and declared what I wanted to show.

```
namespace MyProject.ViewModels
{
    public class HiveViewModel
    {

        //Hive 1
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }

        //Hive 2
        public string location { get; set; }

        //Hive 3
        public string propulsion { get; set; }

        //Hive 4
        public string bhp { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I then added the controller code to select the data

```
public ActionResult data_read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
        var datacontext = db.Hive1.AsQueryable();

        IQueryable<HiveViewModel> thevessel = from c in datacontext
                     select new HiveViewModel
                     {
                         //Hive 1
                         id = c.id,
                         name = c.name,

                         //Hive 2
                         location = c.Hive2.location,

                         //Hive 3
                         propulsion = c.Hive3.propulsion,

                         //Hive 4
                         bhp = c.Hive4.bhp                                                   
                                           };
        DataSourceResult result = thevessel.ToDataSourceResult(request);

        return Json(result);
    }
```

At this stage everything compiles and there are no problems.  When I run the project however and the application attempts to read the data I get an error which is.

```
{"The specified type member 'location' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."}
```

I'm not sure how how to resolve this error or what I've done wrong, I thought logically the above was ok, obviously not though :(

Comment: The property location may be an object that required a constructor (new).  IN the Hive class create a constructor that initializes location.

Answer (score 0):

Try extracting the c.Hive2.location call e.g.

```
public ActionResult data_read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var datacontext = db.Hive1.AsQueryable();
    var loc = c.Hive2.location;
    IQueryable<HiveViewModel> thevessel = from c in datacontext
                 select new HiveViewModel
                 {
                     //Hive 1
                     id = c.id,
                     name = c.name,

                     //Hive 2
                     location = loc,

                     //Hive 3
                     propulsion = c.Hive3.propulsion,

                     //Hive 4
                     bhp = c.Hive4.bhp                                                   
                                       };
    DataSourceResult result = thevessel.ToDataSourceResult(request);

    return Json(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure how this query is transformed to SQL. I would try to change it to

```
public ActionResult data_read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request){
    var datacontext = db.Hive1.AsQueryable();

    var hives = (from c in datacontext).ToList();

    IQueryable<HiveViewModel> thevessel = hives.ForEach(c =>
                 select new HiveViewModel
                 {
                     //Hive 1
                     id = c.id,
                     name = c.name,

                     //Hive 2
                     location = c.Hive2.location,

                     //Hive 3
                     propulsion = c.Hive3.propulsion,

                     //Hive 4
                     bhp = c.Hive4.bhp                                                   
                                       });
```